# Best user interface for selecting a number on an iPhone?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ui-design

This is a question about good UI design for an iPhone app. It feels like a really easy / obvious question but I'm really struggling to find good examples of this done elsewhere so I'll go ahead and ask:

I have a settings page where I want the user to be able to enter how many rows of data to display in the main app. So it's essentially a numeric field, possibly also with a "No limit" option as well. Often I've seen this solved with a list of predetermined options (1, 2, 5, 10, No Limit) but I would prefer to allow the user to enter any number they like. I would use just a plain numeric text field but the built in numeric keypad on iOS has no 'Done' button which seems to overcomplicate things with that approach.

What's a good control / UI approach to use? Feel free to submit an example from another app.

Comment: A good place to check for UI designs that others are using is the Pttrns website. In this instance check the listings for Filter (http://pttrns.com/patterns?scid=38) and Settings (http://pttrns.com/patterns?scid=16)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a slider would do: first position could be No limit. A connected label could show the value. However, yes a slider has finite values, but there should be a reasonable limit. It's easy to use, no hitting keyboard buttons.

[image]

Comment: Do you think intuitively it makes more sense if "No Limit" is all the way to the right?

Answer (score 1):

I'd still use a `UITextField` with the `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` keyboard type. Generally speaking, I don't think the lack of a done button is a huge deal -- you can dismiss the keyboard by responding to touches outside the keyboard's frame or with a `UIBarButtonItem` (this is pretty common when the `UITextField` is part of a `UITableViewCell`, for example, editing a phone number in the Contacts app). If you absolutely need a done button, you can always [add your own](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key).